# jQuery is not able to slide the element back slideUp?

Tags: jquery

I have created a fancy jquery page in my dummy site and added a few animations but the problem is its not behaving as i am programming it to do. Problem is that when i click on any faq question it slides down but when i click again it should slide back up. One way i achieved the goal but then i was not able to change the minus sign back to plus.
Here is the link to fiddlejs to see the behaviour:

SlideUp doesn't work:
https://jsfiddle.net/ocxv257t/

SlideUp works but "-" sign doesn't return to "+":
https://jsfiddle.net/ocxv257t/1/

HTML CODE:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 60px;border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;padding-top: 60px;">Frequently asked questions</h1>
<div class="span6">
   <div class="first">
      <div class="">
         <h5 class="q 1"><span class="plus">+ </span>How do I register myself as a seller on Something.com?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 1">In order to register, please fill a simple registration form above. We will respond to you after reviewing your information at the earliest.</p>
         <h5 class="q 2"><span class="plus">+ </span>What are the charges of Sell on something program?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 2">Listing of products on something.com is absolutely free. something does not charge anything to you for listing your catalogue online. 
            You only pay a small commission for what you sell. The commission structure is shared and agreed with you at the time of registration.
         </p>
         <h5 class="q 3"><span class="plus">+ </span>Who can sell on something.com?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 3">To sell on something.com you should be able to meet following criteria: You should be authorised to sell in UAE You can only sell new & 
            genuine products through something.com You can be any of the following: Manufacturer, Wholesaler, Distributor, Retailer There are few exceptions 
            to the rule for which you may contact us.
         </p>
         <h5 class="q 4"><span class="plus">+ </span>What products can I sell on something.com?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 4">You can sell items in the following categories: Baby Products, Beauty, Books, Consumer Electronics (including Cameras and Video Games - Consoles),
            Digital Accessories (including Mobile Accessories, Electronics Accessories and PC Accessories), Home, Jewellery, Kitchen, Luggage, Mobile Phones, 
            Movies, Music, Personal Care Appliances, Personal Computers, Tablets, Toys, Video games (consoles and games), Watches, Furniture & Home Furnishings, 
            Stationeries, Men & Women Clothing, Men & Women Accessories (Footwear, Bags, Sunglasses, Perfumes), Health & Sport Accessories (Nutritions, 
            Medicines, Exerciser, Treadmills, Cricket Bat etc), Automotive. Further detailed categories can be seen on our home page. More categories are 
            coming soon. Please Contact Us to know more.
         </p>
         <h5 class="q 5"><span class="plus">+ </span>I don't have a website, can I still sell on something.com?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 5">You don't need a website to start selling on something.com. All you would have to do is list your products on something and start selling.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="span6">
   <div class="third">
      <div class="">
         <h5 class="q 6"><span class="plus">+ </span>How do I list my products on something.com?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 6">Once the registration process is complete our team will work closely with you to create your online catalogue. You will also be given access to 
            online panels through which you can easily manage your listings.
         </p>
         <h5 class="q 7"><span class="plus">+ </span>How does selling on something.com work?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 7">Selling on something.com is very easy. First you list the products that you want to sell on something.com marketplace. Customer sees your product 
            and makes a purchase. You will receive an email to ship the product. You deliver the product to the customer and confirm shipment. something will 
            deposit the funds into your selected bank account (as per the payment term) after deducting its fees.
         <h5 class="q 8"><span class="plus">+ </span>Can I sell outside UAE through something.com?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 8">No. At this time, something.com allows shipments only within UAE.</p>
         <h5 class="q 9"><span class="plus">+ </span>If I list my products on something.com, will the customer know that he or she is purchasing from me on something.com?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 9">We will clearly indicate on our product detail pages and offer listing pages that the product is sold by you and the invoice will carry your name.</p>
         <h5 class="q 10"><span class="plus">+ </span>Can I cancel my subscription?</h5>
         <p class="ans q 10">You are free to cancel anytime.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('p.ans').hide();

    $('h5.q').click(function() {
        $(".minus").each(function(i) {
            $('h5.q').find("span").html("+ ").removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");
        });

        if($(this).find("span").hasClass("plus")){$(this).find("span").html("&ndash; ").removeClass("plus").addClass("minus"); $('p.ans').hide();}
        else{$(this).find("span").html("+ ").removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");}

        $('p.ans.' + $(this).attr('class').split(' ').join('.')).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: in the second jsfiddle everything is working file .Also the "-" turns to "+"

Comment: Yes it works as long as click on the same question but when i first click on one question and then click on another the second time, first '-' doesn't return to '+'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with your code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('p.ans').hide();
            $('h5.q').click(function() {
                if($(this).find("span").hasClass("plus")){
                    $("h5").each(function(i) {
                       $('h5.q').find("span").html("+ ").removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");
                       });
                    $(this).find("span").html("&ndash; ").removeClass("plus").addClass("minus"); $('p.ans').hide();
                }
                else{
                    $(this).find("span").html("+ ").removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");
                    $("h5").each(function(i) {
                        $('h5.q').find("span").html("+ ").removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");
                    });
                }   
                $('p.ans.' + $(this).attr('class').split(' ').join('.')).slideToggle();
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better and simpler solution to your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/ocxv257t/4/

Simplified jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var opened = false;
    $("h5.q").click(function() {
        // Close other questions
        $("h5.q").not($(this)).removeClass("opened");
        $(".ans").slideUp();

        if($(this).hasClass("opened")) {
            // Close clicked question
            $(this).removeClass('opened');
            $(this).next(".ans").slideUp();
        } else {
            // Open clicked question
            $(this).addClass('opened');
            $(this).next(".ans").slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Added CSS:

```
h5.q:before {
    content: "+";
}

h5.q.opened:before {
    content: "-";
}
```

Comment: This is close, but you can't close an opened section.

Comment: Its the same problem again in solution, slideUp is not minimizing the question.

Comment: @RickHitchcock It's working great now, I updated the code and the jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want no more than one opened section at a time, this should do it:

```
$(function() {
  $('p.ans').hide();

  $('h5.q').click(function() {
    var p= $(this).next('p'),
        span= $(this).find('span');

    $('.ans').not(p).slideUp();
    p.slideToggle();
    $('h5.q > span').not(span).text('+ ');
    span.text(function(_,t) {
      return t.trim()==='+' ? '- ' : '+ ';
    });
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bu2auxbj/)